# How to insert data into a Django User Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a UserProfile model which has a one-to-one relationship with the Django User Model.

I would like to insert data into the UserProfile model via the view `AddStory`, but I'm getting `IntegrityError at /AddStory/ NOT NULL constraint failed: portal_userprofile.user_id`

More specifically, I want to add some text into ShoppingHistory attribute of UserProfile model via a form given on the homepage. I have another page which lists the value of this attribute(if given by the user) on `ShoppingHistory.html`.

All the users are unique, how do I ensure that this attribute is added for particular user, once that user has logged in? How do I reference the user once he/she has logged in?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):      
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)
    StaffMember = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ShoppingHistory = models.TextField()
    ShoppingWishList = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from portal import models
from portal.forms import UserProfileForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# Create your views here.
def register(request):

regStatus = False

if request.method == 'POST':
    #grab info from raw information
    profile_form=UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

    if profile_form.is_valid():
        user=profile_form.save(commit=False)

        #hash the password for security using the djangohash default method
        user.set_password(user.password)


        if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
            profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']
        user.save()

        regStatus = True

    else:
        print profile_form.errors

else:
    profile_form = UserProfileForm()

return render(request, 'register.html', {'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': regStatus})

def user_login(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid login credentials')

else:
    return render(request, 'login.html', {})

@login_required
def homepage(request):


return render(request, 'home.html', {})


def AddStory(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    story = request.POST.get('ShoppingHistory')
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    p=models.UserProfile(ShoppingHistory=story, username=username)
    p.save()

    return render(request, 'ShoppingHistory.html', {'story': p})
return render(request, 'ShoppingHistory.html', {})
```

**Home.html:**

```
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p> WELCOME, thanks for logging in {{user.username}} </p>
    <form id="user_form" method="post" action="/AddStory/" enctype="multipart/form-data">      
        {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="ShoppingHistory" value="" />
    <input  name="username" value="{{user.username}}" DISABLED />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Story" />

    {% endif %}
```

**ShoppingHistory.html:**

```
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% csrf_token %}

    <p> WELCOME, thanks for logging in {{user.username}} </p>
    <p> Your Shopping Stories: </p>
    <p>{{user.ShoppingHistory}}</p>

    {% endif %}
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from portal.models import UserProfile
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'profile_pic')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much more better to create a custom user using AbstractUser:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Your problem is that when you create a UserProfle instanse you have to set User to it, but actually you want to create it, so you need to create a User first and then you will have to user tables in DB. For what?

more about custom users: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)

**UPDATE:**

The error is in this line`p=models.UserProfile(ShoppingHistory='story',)`. Your UserProfile model requires user to create a UserProfile and you don't set a user instanse. But I want to say that you have a wrong approach of creating custom user. The idea is that you have two user table in your database. One for User and another for UserProfile. They are connected through OneToOne relation but it's not inheritance. Whenever you want to create a UserProfile instance you need to have a User instance created for it already. That's the thing and that's why I would definitely recommend you to use AbstractUser to create a custom User model. Then you don't need to think about specifying a user when creating a user.

**UPDATE 2**

You don't need to create a new user if you want to create a story for him. You can just:

```
def AddStory(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        story = request.POST.get('ShoppingHistory')
        request.user.ShoppingStory = story
        request.user.save()

        return render(request, 'ShoppingHistory.html', {'story': story})
    return render(request, 'ShoppingHistory.html', {})
```

Comment: Yes, I have created a User. I've edited my question accordingly. I have the user tables. I want to add details for ShoppingHistory attribute via an HTML form or django form. @pythad please see the edits

Comment: @thematroids, the error is in this line`p=models.UserProfile(ShoppingHistory='story',)`

Comment: I tried `p=models.UserProfile(ShoppingHistory='story')` but I get `NOT NULL constraint failed: portal_userprofile.user_id`.  What's the correct syntax for inserting that data?

Comment: @thematroids, I've update my answer. I just want to say that your approach is very bad. If you really want to use your models design you have to write something like this `p=models.UserProfile(ShoppingHistory='story', user=...)` as you UserProfile requires a user instance. But where would you get it from?

Comment: Thanks! I tried to re-create my model, but I'm greeted with ` HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'UserProfile.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.` this error. I've updated my code. Could you please suggest some more revisions? makemigrations/syncdb/migrate doesn't seem to work

Comment: @thematroids, try to add `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app_name.UserProfile'` into your `settings.py`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But I'm still unable to store data into the database. `p=models.UserProfile(ShoppingHistory='abcd', username=username)`. Globalname username not defined!

Comment: @thematroids, where do you use this this piece of code? Update you question with your changes please

Comment: I've updated views.py and home.html. I'm trying to send the username by POST method, and now the error is `NOT NULL constraint failed: portal_userprofile.username`

Comment: @thematroids, I've updated my answer. The thing is that you don't need to create a new user when you want to add a story for him, you want to use existing user, not a new one

Comment: AWESOME!  That worked...On a side note, if I want to store a list in the ShoppingHistory variable with two tuples. Such as List A [ first.title, first.link, second.title,second.link, ... ]. Should I use JSON-formatted string, assuming I want to append new items or modify existing items frequently?

Comment: @thematroids, probably yes, it will be easier to access the data. But maybe there is a way to organize this into one more model? You may have a model to collect info about objects and then just create a relation between User and thing to buy. It is much more better than keeping anything in a single TextField.